# Add menu in Quick book using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

While i am adding menu to quick book using vb.net i am getting following error can i get rid of this error.
"The callback application cannot be found from the CLSID or ProgID provided in the subscription request."

Comment: any body can please reply it urgent i am working on client application need to make it working today itself.....

Comment: It looks like it uses COM for the Callback, are you exposing your vb.net dll to COM interop?

Comment: Actually i am using .exe and creating setup for that with all dependency files.Can you help me in that.

Comment: If you want people to jump to your command, you pay them. That's how stuff works usually. Otherwise, please drop the 'urgent' stuff.

Comment: Can you provide more info, on what your doing with QuickBooks? when is the error popping up?